# C++ Optimizer Bug in Visual Studio 2017 version 15.9.4?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

See erratic behavior with floating point local variables, and was going nuts trying to debug it.  Finally tried turning off C++ Optimization in the VC++2017 IDE and the problems went away.

So, is there any news about known optimizer bugs in VC++2107 ?  I am using version 15.9.4 and these are x64 builds.

Comment: Please provide reproducible example. Maybe you rely on current floating point mode, or getting into undefined behavior.

Comment: Hard to give an example (I should probably do the required work - but right now I don't have time - but here is one pseudo code example of the behavior that I saw: double foo = 0.8763;  DoMyRoutine(bar,"test",3.4); Print(foo);  and the value printed out is -0.0005   -- note that all that happened in between setting foo and printing it was a call to a routine that didn't even have foo passed to it...

Comment: I got a similar Problem since switching to 15.9. I found this link: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/343838/msvc-optimizer-bug-with-fpfast-for-x64.html Not that nearly a year has passed between the first reply and the latest note from the dev team  its still not resolved.

Comment: Even 15.9.19 seems to have this bug! I was able to solve this problem only by installing and using the older VC toolset 14.11 as described here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/side-by-side-minor-version-msvc-toolsets-in-visual-studio-2017/